# BeanShell sampler не импортирует библиотеки

Tags: java, apache, testng, jmeter

Нужно написать простой get запрос, но BeanShell sampler почему-то не хочет импортировать библиотеки

```
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;


 HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 try{


 HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/");
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
 log.info("response :" +response);
 }catch(Exception e){
 log.info("ExceptionKPI :" +e);
 }
```

Вот ошибка

```
WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.BeanShellSampler: Exception executing script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;      import org.apache.http.client.HttpCli . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: HttpPost not found in namespace
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам следует заменить эту строку:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
   ```

   вот на эту:

   ```
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   ```

   ошибка происходит из-за того, что интерпретатор Beanshell не может найти класса [HttpPost](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)
2. Начиная c JMeter версии 3.1 рекомендуется использовать [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) и язык [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), скрипты Groovy компилируются в байткод и исполняются JVM напрямую, в то время как Beanshell интерпретируются при каждом вызове. К тому же Beanshell не поддерживает современного синтаксиса Java и вам придется ограничиваться синтаксисом [Java 5](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/grid/java-5-features-083037.html) (нет генериков, лябмд, и т.д.)